# How to save Icon object into a file via JFileChooser?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, icons, save

I have a JLabel inside which I have saved my ImageIcon like this:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = sample.map(); // a map method create an ImageIcon object
imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
imageLabel.setVisible(true);
```

Now I would like to save this ImageIcon object into a PNG file when clicking on the Save item menu.

```
private void imageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Icon pic = imageLabel.getIcon();

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:/");  

    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(file);    

    // this filter will allow just PNG extension  
    FileFilter filter = new MyCustomFilter2();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

Yes I know that this code is wrong and some part is missing, I think I should somehow save my Icon object called pic into a File object. This is my assumption. How can I do it please?

Thanks for any help,

### Michal.

Here is my source code

```
private void imageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
    Icon image = imageLabel.getIcon();

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getIconWidth(),image.getIconHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();

    File file = new File("outputFile");
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:/");  
    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(file);    

    FileFilter filter = new MyCustomFilter2();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
     {
      ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
      File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

     }
    else
     {
      System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
     }
  }

catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File` object returned by the JFileChooser just represents the location on disk where the user would like to save the file.  After that you'll want to use [ImageIO.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to save the file to disk.

e.g.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
```

If you have an Icon, I think you may need to convert that to a BufferedImage before you can save it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it wont save any file (neither empty). I have edited my post and put code here, could you pls help me? Thanks.

Comment: I see your code creating the graphics object, but I don't see any code to paint the icon. I think there's a method called `paintIcon()` It also looks like your code is saving the buffered image to a file called "outputfile" instead of what the user is choosing from the dialog.